# Installing PostgreSQL 9.0 on RHEL 6.4 (How to get Yum to Include a version of OpenSSL I built from source)

Tags: rhel, compiling, yum, openssl, postgresql

I receive the following errors from **yum install postgresql90-server**:

```
Error: Package: postgresql90-9.0.15-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg90)
       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql90-server-9.0.15-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg90)
       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql90-libs-9.0.15-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg90)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql90-server-9.0.15-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg90)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql90-libs-9.0.15-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg90)
       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
```

The [first result on google](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/BUG-8659-Broken-dependencies-on-RHEL6-for-9-2-6-RPMs-td5781988.html) indicated that postgresql 9+ requires `openssl 1.0.1`.

A `yum info openssl` revelaed that I had openssl 1.0.0. A `yum update openssl` told me that I had the latest upgrade.

So I figured I would build 1.0.1:

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1e
./config
make
make test
make install
```

But now I am at a loss on how I would get yum to realize that I have the right openssl. The `yum install postgresql90-server` results in the same error message above.

I figure if I could sync up yum with my new version of openssl, I would be good.

Answer (score 1):

It won't. You have 3 options if you want yum to deal with your new software.

#### Option #1 - use deadly force

Download the `.rpm` files that you're attempting to install and tell `rpm` to install them for you. You can do this using 1 or a combination of these 2 switches to get what you want.

```
  --nodeps                         do not verify package dependencies
  --force                          short hand for --replacepkgs --replacefiles
```

#### Example

```
$ rpm -ivh --nodeps <rpmfile1> <rpmfile2> ...
```

**NOTE:** I would not do it this way!

#### Option #2 - Repackaging a package.

You'll often run into this scenario, especially with `openssl`. I would download the source rpm (`src.rpm`) file and then install that in a develop area for building RPMs.

**NOTE:** If you don't have one you can use the tool `rpmdev-setuptree` to make one. It's in the package `rpmdevtools`.

You can grab one of the [openssl packages available on Fedora's Koji build service](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=109), for example, [this one](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=479409). You'll want to download the `.src.rpm` package and install it into your dev area (`$HOME/rpmbuild`):

```
$ rpm -ivh http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/openssl/1.0.1e/34.fc21/src/openssl-1.0.1e-34.fc21.src.rpm
```

Once installed you have the skeleton of the pieces that go into a packaged version of `openssl`. I'll often edi the `SPEC/openssl.spec` file and swap in my own `openssl-latest.tar.gz` file.

Once I've done the surgery on this package, you can rebuild it:

```
$ rpmbuild -tb SPEC/openssl.spec
```

As an alternative, if the `.src.rpm` is at a recent level and you just want to rebuild it then do this instead:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild openssl..src.rpm
```

Once you've rebuilt using either method, the resulting RPM file(s) are here:

```
$ $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/openssl-...rpm
```

#### Option #3 - use yum's shell

You can consult this `yum` page for tips on how to deal with a system where you're mixing packages up. This method is more for when you need to do more complex tasks with yum than one can accomplish with a single command line.

- http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/NoDeps

It might be helpful to you here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with installing the exact same RPMs as you.

I tried forcing it but postgres didn't work once installed - despite having the correct libssl it refused to run.

I'd suggest trying to install the RPMs directly but for version 9.0.14 - as far as I can tell the 9.0.15 RPM is broken. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have hit this same problem on CentOS 6.x for PGDG installs from Postgres 9.0 - 9.3. Here was how we resolved it:

First I downloaded and installed the Postgres version I was after:

```
yum install http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat92-9.2-7.noarch.rpm
```

When trying to install the postgresql92 packages, I hit the same error:

```
Error: Package: postgresql92-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) Error: Package: postgresql92-server-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) Error: Package: postgresql92-contrib-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) Error: Package: postgresql92-libs-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) Error: Package: postgresql92-server-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) Error: Package: postgresql92-contrib-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) Error: Package: postgresql92-libs-9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg92)
 Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
```

To resolve (you can use any mirror, I looked up the packages in http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25381551/dir/centos_6/com/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm.html):

```
yum install ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm
yum install ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-devel-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm
yum install ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-static-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm
```

Finally, install the postgres packages you were after (for validation I installed everything):

```
yum install postgresql92*
```

...

```
Installed:   postgresql92.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                  
postgresql92-contrib.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                      
postgresql92-debuginfo.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                
postgresql92-devel.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                        
postgresql92-docs.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                     
postgresql92-jdbc.x86_64 0:9.2.1002-1PGDG.rhel6                      
postgresql92-jdbc-debuginfo.x86_64 0:9.2.1002-1PGDG.rhel6        
postgresql92-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                         
postgresql92-odbc.x86_64 0:09.02.0100-1PGDG.rhel6                
postgresql92-odbc-debuginfo.x86_64 0:09.02.0100-1PGDG.rhel6          
postgresql92-plperl.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                   
postgresql92-plpython.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                     
postgresql92-pltcl.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                    
postgresql92-server.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                       
postgresql92-tcl.x86_64 0:2.0.0-1.rhel6                          
postgresql92-tcl-debuginfo.x86_64 0:2.0.0-1.rhel6                    
postgresql92-test.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1PGDG.rhel6                     

Dependency Installed:   java-1.5.0-gcj.x86_64 0:1.5.0.0-29.1.el6      
java_cup.x86_64 1:0.10k-5.el6         jpackage-utils.noarch
0:1.7.5-3.12.el6           libart_lgpl.x86_64 0:2.3.20-5.1.el6        
libgcj.x86_64 0:4.4.7-3.el6           libtool-ltdl.x86_64
0:2.2.6-15.5.el6             libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.26-2.el6_3.1        
sinjdoc.x86_64 0:0.5-9.1.el6          unixODBC.x86_64
0:2.2.14-12.el6_3                uuid.x86_64 0:1.6.1-10.el6           

Complete!
```